# Орфография и грамматика

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Меню Ворда предлагает проверку "орфографии и грамматики". А разве это не одно и то же?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за вопрос.
Дело, конечно, не в Ворде. Тут действительно терминологическая закавыка, некоторое недопонимание или разночтение имеет место.
Орфография — это, как следует из прямого перевода, правильнописание, т. е. правописание в целом. Однако в силу исторических причин в понимании большинства авторов орфография сведена до правильности написания "слов и букв", всё остальное стали считать пунктуацией. Даже в школе ошибки с незапамятных времен стали разделять на орфографические и пунктуационные.

С другой стороны, пунктуация обычно подаётся как часть синтаксиса, что в общем-то довольно логично, ибо пунктуация процентов на 90 определяется именно им. Ну а то, что синтаксис — главная из серьезно изучаемых в школе составляющих грамматики предложения, это уже понятно. Вот и получается, что в понимании некоторых правописание делится не на орфографию (в узком смысле) и пунктуацию — что было вполне резонно, — а на правописание и грамматику.

Вместе с тем, нельзя забывать, что Ворд проверяет (или пытается проверять) не только запятые, но и грамматику слов и сочетаний (грамматическую основу, падежи, спряжение глаголов, наличие объекта) — т. е. то, что иначе как грамматикой ну уж никак не назовешь.

Таким образом, наиболее точно вопрос должен бы звучать так: "Проверка орфографии, пунктуации и грамматики". Ну или "орфографии и синтаксиса" —  это если немного сужать функцию.

Answer (score 6):

**Грамматическая ошибка** — это ошибка в структуре языковой единицы, в структуре слова, словосочетания, предложения; это нарушение какой-либо грамматической нормы — словообразовательной, морфологической, синтаксической. Например: *раздумчивый* (взгляд) вместо *задумчивый*, *благородность* вместо *благородство* (ошибка в словообразовательной структуре слова, использование не той приставки, не того суффикса);
без комментарий, более правильнее (неправильно образована форма слова, т.е. нарушена морфологическая норма);

**Орфографическая ошибка** — это ошибка в правильном написании орфограмм (букв) в слове.  Орфографическая ошибка может быть допущена только на письме, обычно в слабой фонетической позиции (для гласных — в безударном положении, для согласных — на конце слова или  перед другим согласным) или в слитно-раздельно-дефисных написаниях. Такую ошибку можно только увидеть, услышать её нельзя: на площаде, о синим карандаше, небыл, кто то, полапельсина.

В письменной речи мы чаще сталкиваемся с орфографическими ошибками, а грамматические чаще допускаем в устной речи.

Comment: Это да, по школьным понятиям. Вся штука в том, что Ворд вкладывает несолько другой смысл, в чем легко убедиться, проанализировав зеленое и красное (обычно - так) подчеркивание.

Comment: По поводу программы Ворд (немного в сторону). Хорошо, что такая программа существует, она облегчает работу, но "живые" знания не заменит (пока что!). Ворд не чувствует языка, речи, в принципе, как и онлайн-переводчик. Но, повторяю, как хорошо, что такие программы созданы. Хоть обратишь внимание на ошибку, на которой бы и не заострилось внимание.

Comment: > небыл, кто то, полапельсина

Это разве орфографические ошибки? Это скорее ошибки грамматические, т.к. связаны с разбивкой на слова и пунктуацией. См. - не был (не с глаголами раздельно), кто-то (через дефис), пол-апельсина (вроде так, да?) или пол апельсина (я и не знал, что бывают апельсины-мальчики и апельсины-девочки)???

Comment: Слитно-раздельно-дефисные написания - это орфографические ошибки, а пол-апельсина - это половина апельсина, а не принадлежность к женскому или мужскому роду.

Comment: Ворд хорошо, что есть, если бы безграмотные деффачки им пользовались... А то как почитаешь...

Answer (score 1):

Орфография - часть грамматики, но есть ведь специфические орфографические правила и особые грамматические. Соответственно и ошибки бывают орфографические и грамматические